# Detect base control properties against user control properties

Tags: c#

Is there any way to detect if a property is from the base control and not from my user control? I'm using reflection to get the list of properties

```
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            --Making something with the propery
        }
```

This process gives me all the properties, the ones of the base control and the ones I defined in my user control. I need to have a list of the properties of the user control only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` when fetching the types:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Alternatively, you can inspect the `DeclaringType` property of `PropertyInfo`:

```
if (property.DeclaringType == type)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! So simple! That did the trick. Thank you C.Evenhuis